# Displaying form elements obtained from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a questions table which has a variety of questions of different input types.  The format in my seeder is like so

```
 DB::table('questions')->insert([
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'text' => 'Name',
]);

DB::table('questions')->insert([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'select',
            'text' => 'Title',
            'values' => serialize(['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms']),
            'class' => 'selectpicker'
]);
```

So you can see the above I have one text input and one select, which has serialized list of values.  Now within my controller I get the Questions and pass it to my view.

Within my view, I am doing something like the following

```
@foreach($questions as $q)
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="{{ $q["type"] }}" 
                class="form-control {{ $q["class"] }}"
                id="{{ $q["name"] }}" 
                name="questions[{{ $q["id"] }}]"
        >
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Where I am having difficulty is with the select inputs.  How would I go about displaying my selects along with their options (values)?

Thanks

Comment: It's a really bad design, you should more often than not, separate your html from database entries.

Comment: When it is an extremely large form however, does it not make sense to store the questions in the database?  The form has over 100 fields,  over multiple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list you can check the type of `$q` in your foreach. The code inside your loop would look like this:

```
@if( $q['type'] === 'select' )
    <select name="questions[{{ $q['id'] }}]">
        @foreach( unserialize($q['values']) as $v )
            <option value="{{ $v }}">{{ $v }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endif
```